# Criar uma lista de características ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby, lista, objetos

estou tentando a alguns dias mas não consegui resolver meu problema. Preciso criar uma lista de características para um item e posteriormente listar todas elas. Gostaria que pudessem me auxiliar ou me passar algum tutorial sobre. 
 

 
Bem eu tenho um cadastro de pessoa e gostaria de incluir neste cadastro diversas "características". Atualmente gerei dois cadastros, um de pessoa e outro de característica, mas não estou conseguindo associar os dois. 

 
 Utilizei o belongs_to porém, é apenas um caso. Gostaria que as características pudessem ser utilizadas em varias pessoas e varias pessoas possuíssem diversas características.

 
Como posso fazer está associação? Como posso listar todas as características depois?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez você possa resolver sua questão estudando [esta seção](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/_single-page#sec-the_relationship_model) do Rails Tutorial, cuja abordagem é demonstrada na figura abaixo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.